# jsf primefaces how to use p:focus in p:tabview

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, focus, tabview

I'm creating some pages with inputs that have to be validated. I'm using p:focus on this pages and works like charm. When some field is not validating correctly when I press the save button, the page focus on this field.

The problem comes when I try the same in a tabview page. The p:focus is not working correctly because is not focusing on the tab where the field failed validating.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks.